# Google Maps API and IE6

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I was wondering if anyone knows more about the inner workings of the Google Maps API when paired with Internet Explorer 6. I want to know more about data confidentiality when using this odd couple. What exactly is sent to the google servers? There isn't much information about this. In one of the few posts on the subject ([groups.google.co.in](http://groups.google.co.in/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/eefa728a32989de1/bc55396e1455b4e9?lnk=gst&q=confidentiality#bc55396e1455b4e9)), it is explained that, for example, browsers which doesn't support SVG or VML send placemark/polygon/polyline information to google, where the map will be rendered and sent back. From what I've found, IE6 does not have support for SVG or VML and thus, not capable of rendering the information by itself. Does anyone know more about this?

Comment: What kind of confidentiality concerns do you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE6 has VML support, even IE5.0 has (see [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language))

Google maps uses VML on IE browsers and SVG on the others.